# Kendo Calender with appointment viewer

Tags: asp.net, calendar, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi is there any way to display appointments for the selected dates in the Kendo calender control?

Something like, if I've an appointment on 1st Jan my calender should show a message along with date (in the same kendo calender control). And the remaining dates would be normal style only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show custom content on each date by defining a template function when you declare the calendar. This function will be called for each date shown in the calendar. The following example shows how to do this:

```
// Define dates that have appointments
var calDates = [];
calDates[+new Date(2013, 0, 1)] = [{ Description: "Appointment foo", Time: "09:00"}];
calDates[+new Date(2013, 0, 2)] = [{ Description: "Appointment bar", Time: "10:00" }, { Description: "Appointment baz", Time: "12:00"}];

// Declare Kendo Calendar
$("#div1").kendoCalendar({ "value": new Date(2013, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "month": { "content": "#= BuildDateMarker(data) #"} });

// Template function
function BuildDateMarker(data) {

    // Get any appointments for this date       
    var appointments = calDates[+data.date];

    if (!appointments || appointments == 'undefined') {
        // No appointments for this date, so return default marker (day of the month)
        return data.date.getDate();
    }

    // Open marker
    var marker = '<div class="appointments" title="' + data.date + '">';

    // Add item for each of this date's appointments
    for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
        var appointment = appointments[i];
        marker += '<span class="appointment">' + appointment.Description + ', at ' + appointment.Time + '</span>';
    }

    // Close marker
    marker += '</div>';

    return marker;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.. this is what exactly I'm looking for. And one more thing is there any way to select entire week? or month? and I wanted to display no.of appointments for the week at the end of each week. Is it possible with Kendo Calendar?

Comment: You want to select entire week or entire month if there is an appointment on any date in that week or that month?

Comment: For example I've appointment on 17th April and 19th April, then I wanted to show 2 at the end of week (Probly add another row to display weeks totals)

Comment: And one more thing.. I wanted to pass the array of appointments from my controller not from here. How can we pass?

Comment: This could get ugly, but as a starting point 'BuildDateMarker' would need figure out the week-ending date of the provided date, and add the total number of appointments for that date to an external dictionary whose keys are week-ending dates and whose values are the number of appointments for that week. Then when the calendar has completed building, scan the dictionary and add a new TD containing the number of appointments for each week to the end of the appropriate calendar row.

Comment: Thanks Netricity, can you tell me how to bind the same data from controller? I'm just new to Kendo. I wanted to pass these values from controller

Comment: In the Controller action method, add the necessary data to ViewBag.CalendarDates, then in the View loop thru ViewBag.CalendarDates to build up the JavaScript array.
Or you could create a Kendo datasource that pulls the data from another controller, see http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview.
This needs answering fully in a separate question really.

Comment: Hi Netricity, is there any example to add no.of appointments for each week in a seperate TD? I tried but failed to get it